# Can you do webkit css transformations on a webkit box reflection?

Tags: webkit, css

Much like how you can add -webkit-gradient to a -webkit-box-reflect, can you perform a transformation on the reflection? The image I am reflecting is at an angle and I wanted to try and rotate the reflection or skew it slightly to make it match the bottom of the image its reflecting.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly transform a reflection.

However, you can hack this effect by putting a copy of the image into a div with overflow:hidden, and absolutely positioning the image within the div to hide the image itself, then you can skew/rotate it appropriately, and position the div with the new rotated/skewed shadow below the original image. This is sheer hackery - but it does get you what you want...